# How to extract and/or remove the last page of a bunch of PDFs?

Tags: linux, pdf

One of our vendors started tacking on an unnecessarily huge image to the last page of PDFs we get from them. I need to trim this out. However, we have hundreds of these, so it's prohibitive to go in manually. What're the best ways to extract and then delete (Preferably first one, then the other; I still need to confirm via filesize that I'm not deleting one which doesn't have the image) the last page of a PDF automatically? OS is Linux.

I can extract it using ghostscript, with something along the lines of `gs -dFirstPage=5 -dLastPage=5`, but I need to automate this, I can't go through and manually find out what the number of the last page is.

Any ideas?

Edit: To clarify, I simply want to split out/delete the last page. Not the image in it, excise the last page period.

Comment: Look at [`pdftk`](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) — I'm positive it can be made to work in general for this kind of task.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Unix: convert pdf to image](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/convert-pdf-to-image-jpegpng)

Comment: Not remotely a duplicate of that.

Comment: I feel like I should clarify though: I'm not interested in removing an image on the last page. I'm interested in removing the last page, period.

Comment: Related question with multiple different answers on Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221962/how-can-i-extract-a-page-range-a-part-of-a-pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Daniel Andersson already commented, this can easily be done with `pdftk`:

```
pdftk input.pdf cat end-1 output temp.pdf
pdftk temp.pdf  cat end-2 output output.pdf
rm temp.pdf
```

I don't know if it can be done with one call to pdftk though...

**Edit**: you could combine it with thanosk's answer and use (in bash):

```
pdftk input.pdf cat 1-$((last-1)) output output.pdf
```

when you already extracted the last page to the variable `$last`.

Comment: Example does not work. Found @Sid Steward's answer to work better.

Answer (score 17):

To further improve on @eldering's answer, pdftk version 1.45 and later have the means to reference pages in reverse order by prepending the lower-case letter r to the page number.  The final page in a PDF is r1, the next-to-last page is r2, etc.

For example, the single pdftk call:

```
pdftk input.pdf cat 1-r2 output output.pdf
```

will drop the final page from input.pdf -- the input should be at least two pages long.

To extract just the final page of a PDF in order to test its filesize, run:

```
pdftk input.pdf cat r1 output final_page.pdf
```

Pdftk is available on Linux.  Many distros have a binary you can install.  You should make sure it is version 1.45 or later, though.  If not, you can build pdftk from source code.

Comment: the rN-thing is exactly what I needed, because my latex based pdf generating system always produced some empty pages at the beginning and nearly at the end of the document, I had to remove them manually at the end. Now I just call: pdftk A=pocket20.pdf cat A3-r6 r3-end output pocket_to_print.pdf which removes the first two and the 4th,5th last pages.

Answer (score 2):

pdfinfo will give you the size of the actual pdf file, and pdfimages will give you an index of the images in the said pdf file. So you can write a script in the form

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.pdf
do
        j=$(pdfinfo "$i" |awk '/^Pages/ { print $2}')
        pdfimages -list -p -f "$j" "$i"
done
```

that should return if a particular file has an image in the last page. 
If it does then you can do whatever manipulation you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

A one liner solution would be to use `find` along `pdftk`:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" -exec pdftk {} cat 1-r2 output cut/{} \;
```

**NOTE**: the cropped files are stored in this example in a subdirectory called `cut` to keep the original filename as `pdftk` does not allow overwriting input files.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using pdfjam instead of pdftk:

```
#!/bin/sh
fname=`basename $1`
pdfjam $1 1-$((`pdfinfo $1 | grep Pages | grep -shoPe '\d+'` - ${2:-1})) -o ${fname%.*}-trimmed.pdf
```

Where the first argument is the file to trim and the second argument the amount of pages to trim (defaults to 1).

Answer (score 0):

I used windows powershell script to remove last page of pdf files:

```
$destFolder = "your dest folder to store new files after cutting last page"
$pdfFiles = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf

foreach ($pdfFile in $pdfFiles) {
    pdftk $pdfFile cat 1-r2 output "$destFolder $pdfFile.pdf"
}
```

!!!!!
Your have to install pdftk on your PC:
scoop install pdftk